# How can we change the image preview properties in rstudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using rmarkdown in rstudio, you can generate in-line image previews pretty easily. However, whenever I specify fig.width and fig.height for the chunk, the image preview (not the knitr rendering) seems to just fill in the page and not follow the same scaling. Is there a way to also affect the image preview sizing?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you displaying the image? Because the inline code in Rmarkdown, is Markdown code and usually is **outside** the R chunk, your fig.width and fig.height arguments inside the chunk may not be affecting the image like you would want. Give us a little code reprex so we can see what the exact issue is.

Comment: When you run inline a single chunk, the image is previewed in the Rmarkdown page directly underneath that chunk. It's that image preview I am talking about. I can render the image with knitr fine.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the `imager` package we can achieve your desired output.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height=5, fig.width=5}
library(imager)
im <- load.image('image.png')
plot(im, axes=FALSE)
```
````

Which displays the image like this

[image]

Now changing our `fig.width` and `fig.height` chunk arguments, we get a different RStudio image preview size. which outputs below.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=10}
library(imager)
im <- load.image('image.png')
plot(im, axes=FALSE)
```
````

[image]